# No Db Request on TryGetObjectByKey - alternative?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would need a method that does the same like this method:

`TryGetObjectByKey` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738728(v=vs.110).aspx

but without trying to fetch it from the database, so just I check if EntityKey exists in ObjectStataManager or not.

Is there a inbuilt method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectStateManager has method [TryGetObjectStateEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359762%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which tries to get ObjectStateEntry with specified EntityKey. This method will not try to load object from data source if it is not found in ObjectStateManager.

```
ObjectStateEntry entry;
if (manager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(key, out entry))
    // entity exists
```

Also keep in mind that you can use [`Local`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) property of appropriate set to check if entity is loadded.

Comment: I have used Local already, but I just couldnt believe that there is no inbuilt function for this. Thx working like a charm.